# problem with compiling wstring on linux with cpprestsdk

Tags: c++, linux, cpprest-sdk

I have code something like this

```
using namespace web;                
using namespace http;   

const http_response& response = /*valid assignment*/
http_headers::const_iterator it = response.headers().find(L"SomeKey");
if (it != response.headers().end())
    {
        //doing something
    }
```

`response` is having valid data.
It is compiling with windows. I want to compile the same snippet in Linux with g++. How should I handle this?
Do I need to add some flags for compiling?
I got error like this:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘web::http::http_headers::find(const wchar_t [17]) const’
   http_headers::const_iterator it = response.headers().find(L"SomeKey");
                                                                       ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project use `wstring` for windows, `string` for Linux. And they provide a type `string_t` and a macro `U` to help deal with this, your code needs to be changed to be compiled both on Windows and Linux.

> What is utility::string_t and the 'U' macro? The C++ REST SDK uses a
> different string type dependent on the platform being targeted. For
> example for the Windows platforms utility::string_t is std::wstring
> using UTF-16, on Linux std::string using UTF-8. The 'U' macro can be
> used to create a string literal of the platform type. If you are using
> a library causing conflicts with the 'U' macro, for example
> Boost.Iostreams it can be turned off by defining the macro
> '_TURN_OFF_PLATFORM_STRING' before including the C++ REST SDK header
> files.

See this [FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/FAQ)

A tipical usage:

```cpp
static const utility::string_t wl_birthday = U("wl.birthday");
static const utility::string_t wl_basic = U("wl.basic");
```

And for your code:

```cpp
http_headers::const_iterator it = response.headers().find(U("SomeKey"));
```

WARN about the [status](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk) of this project:

> cpprestsdk is in maintenance mode and we do not recommend its use in new projects. We will continue to fix critical bugs and address security issues.